# MoveFileEx() File removal on reboot

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Currently I can remove a directory on reboot. Im currently doing this by using the `MoveFileEx` function along with passing the `MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT`constant.

My question is if I have the following:

Directory 1 and inside I have Directory 2... Directory 2 is unistalled which means the directory needs to be removed but as there was only one directory within directory 1 It means i can just remove Directory 1 which will in turn remove directory 2. But lets say after I have marked Directory 1 to be removed on reboot Another Directory has been installed into Directory 1 called Directory 3. In this scenario only Directory 2 should be removed as we dont wont to remove Directory 3.

I was wondering if there is any conditional variables / constants which could help on this situation?

Comment: [MoveFileEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365240.aspx): *"The system deletes a directory that is tagged for deletion with the **MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT** flag only if it is empty."* The documentation should be your first source of information. Try it!

Comment: I actually seen this after i posted the question @IInspectable.. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that if a directory or file is not marked to be deleted then the directory in which it is in will not be deleted. (Just as IInspectable noted)

> "The system deletes a directory that is tagged for deletion with the
>   MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT flag only if it is empty."

Answer (score 0):

> But lets say after I have marked Directory 1 to be removed on reboot Another Directory has been installed into Directory 1 called Directory 3. In this scenario only Directory 2 should be removed as we dont wont to remove Directory 3.

There is no API to "unmark" a file/directory that has been marked for deletion on reboot.  You would have to update the Registry directly to remove an item from the list.  The [`MoveFileEx()` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365240.aspx) tells you which Registry key is used:

> The function stores the locations of the files to be renamed at restart in the following registry value:
>
> **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\PendingFileRenameOperations**
>
> This registry value is of type REG_MULTI_SZ. Each rename operation stores one of the following NULL-terminated strings, depending on whether the rename is a delete or not:
>
> - *szDstFile\0\0*
> - *szSrcFile\0szDstFile\0*
>
> The string *szDstFile\0\0* indicates that the file *szDstFile* is to be deleted on reboot. The string *szSrcFile\0szDstFile\0* indicates that *szSrcFile* is to be renamed *szDstFile* on reboot.

On the other hand, the documentation also says:

> The system deletes a directory that is tagged for deletion with the MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT flag **only if it is empty. To ensure deletion of directories, move or delete all files from the directory before attempting to delete it**. Files may be in the directory at boot time, but they must be deleted or moved before the system can delete the directory.

But that only mentions *files*, not *subdirectories*.